# Eloquont related data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a `ProductCategory` say "Dresses". `Products` are related to product category and images are related to `Products`. I want the list of records with both products, product images for a particular `ProductCategory` id using Laravel 5.2.

I tried:

```
$productCategories = ProductCategory::find(1)->products;
```

This give me related products, but now I want all the related images to the products in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look for eloquent nested relationships eager loading. need to know what kind of relationships and relationship names you are using.

haven't tested but it should work something like this. if many to many relationship come by you may need to use a foreach to loop through finding related model of each.

```
$productCategories = ProductCategory::with('products', 'products.images')->findOrFail(1);
```

Comment: $productCategories = ProductCategory::with('products', 'products.images')->findOrFail(1);
Worked.Thanks